# Core Data Context Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a one-to-many relationship in my core data model.  There can be many foods attached to one meal.  I having a little difficulty with the code and have a few questions.

(1) If I just want to create a bunch of foods and do not want to attach them to a meal.  Will this model accomplish that?  For instance, I want to create Apple, Peach and Pear foods, but I do not want them assigned to a meal.  Must I assign a Meal to each Food?

```
Food *food = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Food" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
food.name = @"Apple";
food.type = @"Fruit";

OR

Meal *meal = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Meal" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

// Create Food (same way as above)

[meal addFoodsObject: food];
```

(2) If I have separate classes each with their own Fetch Controller, does each class need their own context or can I share one from the App Delegate.  For example,  One class displays all the meals, and another displays all the foods.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) So long as your relationship is marked optional (the default) in the model builder, you `Food` objects do not need a `Meal`.

(2) You can use the main `NSManagedObjectContext` from the application delegate, so long as you're not doing anything that would violate its main thread confinement.  (Which it doesn't sound like you are doing...)

Comment: Thank you, there must be something else going on then.  I created a different question, maybe your expertise you help with that question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731062/core-data-one-to-many-fetch-data